# Python - use AND or OR in this code?

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple code to get some easy practice in Python, just to find the maximum out of three numbers, without using the max function.

I wrote this:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
num3 = int(input("Enter the third number: "))

def max_of_three(num1,num2,num3):
    if num1>num2 and num1>num3:
        return num1
    elif num2>num1 and num2>num3:
        return num2
    elif num3>num1 and num3>num2:
        return num3

print (max_of_three(5,7,2))
```

For this specific piece of code, is there a difference between using AND and OR when comparing two numbers? Obviously in other code there's an important difference, but does it matter in getting the result here?

Also I know there's easier ways to write this, but I'm just trying to get back into writing Python.

Replies are appreciated.

Comment: Try the input '5, 2, 7'.

Comment: If all numbers are the same, you want to return None?

Comment: To answer the question, though, does using OR even make sense logically? Verbally say that a number is the max if it is larger than one AND the other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to alter the operators to make them greater than or equal to `>=` because some numbers may be the same.

Yes there would be a difference if you used `or` instead of `and` because of short-circuiting.

When using `and` to return a boolean value, *both* expressions need to be true for the entire condition to return `True`. If the first expression returns false, then then python will "short-circuit" and automatically return `False`, without even checking the second expression.

On the other hand, when using `or`, only *one* of the expressions has to be true for the condition to return `True`. So when python checks the first expression, if it is true, then the whole condition will short-circuit and return `True`, without even checking the second expression.

so if you replaced `and` with `or` in your first if statement you could have a condition where num1 is greater than num2 but less than num3. Yet this would still return num1 as the max.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

We can get rid of the ANDs and ORs altogether, and eliminate the redundant test (once you've decided to neither return num1 nor num2, why test if you should return num3? There's nothing else left!)  We end up with something overly Pythonish like:

```
def max_of_three(num1, num2, num3):
    if num2 <= num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    if num1 <= num2 >= num3:
        return num2
    return num3
```

where the `num2 <= num1 >= num3` has an implicit AND associated with it which should answer your original question.

To have more fun with computing the maximum sans `max()`, we can extend to two or more values, not just three, by doing something like:

```
def max_of_several(num1, num2, *args):

    larger = (num1, num2)[num1 < num2]

    return max_of_several(larger, *args) if args else larger
```

Comment: Doesn't `if num2 <= num1 >= num3` turn into `(bool value) >= num3`, or vice-versa?

Comment: Not in Python!  `a < b < c` -> `a < b and b < c` but with the advantage that `b` only gets evaluated once, not twice.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but I saw a post once that claimed you couldn't chain comparison operators, and you are just seeing `True < c`, for example, which gets evaluated as `1 < c`

Comment: See paragraph beginning "Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily" under [6.10. Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

Comment: I see. Not sure what the other post I read was saying then. Plus it didn't help that I couldn't come up with a scenario where I saw the boolean comparison behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a difference. The statement **and** requires both the conditions to be true. **Or** would only require one of them to be true. Lets take an example:

1. Num 1 = 1
2. Num 2 = 2
3. Num 3 = 3

Your code, using or, would:

Disregard the first if statement because 1 is not greater than 2 **or** greater than 3.

Accept the second if statement. 2 is greater than one, and the or condition tells the computer that 2 can be greater than 1 or 3 for the statement to be valid. It is greater than 1 so the statement is valid.

Python would then accept this - and not test the last condition because this one has been found true first. 2 would be the output - despite num 3 being bigger than num 2. Here is the some pseudocode with the values substituted in:

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
num3 = 3

IS: num1 > num 2 or num3?
    False

IS: num2 > num1 or num3?
    True. num2 > num1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a difference. Basically, if you replace `and` by `or`, your code no longer works correctly.

The problem is that in each `if` statement, you need both conditions fulfilled to ensure that the value you want to return is larger than any of the others.

Note that you still have a bug in your code: What happens if all three parameters are equal? You need to either change `>` to `>=` or else just return `num3` in the end, instead of checking if num3 is strictly larger than both other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a difference. Say you used

```
if num1>num2 or num1>num3:
    return num1
```

and say we tried `print (max_of_three(2,1,3))` it would return 2, because when it tries `num1>num2 or num1>num3` which evaluates to `True or False` which evaluates to `True` therefore returning num2 instead of num3. if we try with and

```
if num1>num2 and num1>num3:
    return num1
```

and tried `print (max_of_three(2,1,3))` it would return 3 because `num1>num2 and num1>num3` evaluates to `True and False` which evaluates to `False`. `num2>num1 and num2>num3` also evaluates to `False` so we move on. `num3>num1 and num3>num2` turns into `True` so we return num3. (side note: this code will not always return a number if two numbers are the same, for instance `print (max_of_three(3,3,2))` doesn't return anything.)